# How to make 2 subs work in the same UserForm in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I have 2 private sub in the same ''UserForm1''.

I'm using checkboxes to give me an input or generate a number. I can write in sheet1 or in sheet2 depending of the sub runned.

But if I run the macro in one sheet1, i cannot run the other macro in sheet2.

I will need to manually go in sheet2 to run it.

Here is my code :

```
Private Sub ToggleButton1_Click()


If CheckBox1.Value = True And CheckBox4.Value = True And CheckBox7.Value = True And CheckBox2.Value = False And CheckBox3.Value = False _
And CheckBox6.Value = False And CheckBox5.Value = False And CheckBox8.Value = False And CheckBox9.Value = False And CheckBox10.Value = False And CheckBox11.Value = False And CheckBox12.Value = False _
And CheckBox13.Value = False And CheckBox14.Value = False And CheckBox15.Value = False Then

Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B4").Select
ActiveCell.EntireRow.Insert shift:=xlDown

Sheets("sheet2").Range("B4:E4").Select
Selection.Borders.Weight = xlThin

Sheets("sheet2").Range("B4").Select
ActiveCell.Value = "=b5+1"

Sheets("sheet2").Range("A4").Select
Selection.Borders.Weight = xlThin
ActiveCell.Value = "E"
End If

If CheckBox1.Value = True And CheckBox4.Value = True And CheckBox7.Value = False And CheckBox2.Value = False And CheckBox3.Value = False And CheckBox6.Value = False And CheckBox5.Value = True And CheckBox8.Value = False And CheckBox9.Value = False _
And CheckBox10.Value = False And CheckBox11.Value = False And CheckBox12.Value = False And CheckBox13.Value = False And CheckBox14.Value = False And CheckBox15.Value = False Then


Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B4").Select
ActiveCell.EntireRow.Insert shift:=xlDown

Sheets("sheet2").Range("B4:E4").Select
Selection.Borders.Weight = xlThin

Sheets("sheet2").Range("B4").Select
ActiveCell.Value = "=b5+1"

Sheets("sheet2").Range("A4").Select
Selection.Borders.Weight = xlThin
ActiveCell.Value = "PE"
End If

If CheckBox1.Value = True And CheckBox4.Value = True And CheckBox7.Value = False And CheckBox2.Value = False And CheckBox3.Value = False And CheckBox6.Value = True And CheckBox5.Value = False And CheckBox8.Value = True And CheckBox9.Value = False _
And CheckBox10.Value = False And CheckBox11.Value = False And CheckBox12.Value = False And CheckBox13.Value = False And CheckBox14.Value = False And CheckBox15.Value = False Then


Sheets("Sheet3").Range("B4").Select
ActiveCell.EntireRow.Insert shift:=xlDown

Sheets("sheet3").Range("B4:E4").Select
Selection.Borders.Weight = xlThin

Sheets("sheet3").Range("B4").Select
ActiveCell.Value = "=b5+1"

Sheets("sheet3").Range("A4").Select
Selection.Borders.Weight = xlThin
ActiveCell.Value = "OA"
End If


If CheckBox1.Value = True And CheckBox4.Value = True And CheckBox7.Value = False And CheckBox2.Value = False And CheckBox3.Value = False And CheckBox6.Value = True And CheckBox5.Value = False And CheckBox8.Value = False And CheckBox9.Value = True _
And CheckBox10.Value = False And CheckBox11.Value = False And CheckBox12.Value = False And CheckBox13.Value = False And CheckBox14.Value = False And CheckBox15.Value = False Then


Sheets("Sheet3").Range("B4").Select
ActiveCell.EntireRow.Insert shift:=xlDown

Sheets("sheet3").Range("B4:E4").Select
Selection.Borders.Weight = xlThin

Sheets("sheet3").Range("B4").Select
ActiveCell.Value = "=b5+1"

Sheets("sheet3").Range("A4").Select
Selection.Borders.Weight = xlThin
ActiveCell.Value = "OB"
End If

If CheckBox1.Value = True And CheckBox4.Value = True And CheckBox7.Value = False And CheckBox2.Value = False And CheckBox3.Value = False And CheckBox6.Value = True And CheckBox5.Value = False And CheckBox8.Value = False And CheckBox9.Value = False _
And CheckBox10.Value = True And CheckBox11.Value = False And CheckBox12.Value = False And CheckBox13.Value = False And CheckBox14.Value = False And CheckBox15.Value = False Then


Sheets("Sheet3").Range("B4").Select
ActiveCell.EntireRow.Insert shift:=xlDown

Sheets("sheet3").Range("B4:E4").Select
Selection.Borders.Weight = xlThin

Sheets("sheet3").Range("B4").Select
ActiveCell.Value = "=b5+1"

Sheets("sheet3").Range("A4").Select
Selection.Borders.Weight = xlThin
ActiveCell.Value = "OC"
End If

If CheckBox1.Value = True And CheckBox4.Value = True And CheckBox7.Value = False And CheckBox2.Value = False And CheckBox3.Value = False And CheckBox6.Value = True And CheckBox5.Value = False And CheckBox8.Value = False And CheckBox9.Value = False _
And CheckBox10.Value = False And CheckBox11.Value = True And CheckBox12.Value = False And CheckBox13.Value = False And CheckBox14.Value = False And CheckBox15.Value = False Then


Sheets("Sheet3").Range("B4").Select
ActiveCell.EntireRow.Insert shift:=xlDown

Sheets("sheet3").Range("B4:E4").Select
Selection.Borders.Weight = xlThin

Sheets("sheet3").Range("B4").Select
ActiveCell.Value = "=b5+1"

Sheets("sheet3").Range("A4").Select
Selection.Borders.Weight = xlThin
ActiveCell.Value = "OD"
End If

If CheckBox1.Value = True And CheckBox4.Value = True And CheckBox7.Value = False And CheckBox2.Value = False And CheckBox3.Value = False And CheckBox6.Value = True And CheckBox5.Value = False And CheckBox8.Value = False And CheckBox9.Value = False _
And CheckBox10.Value = False And CheckBox11.Value = False And CheckBox12.Value = True And CheckBox13.Value = False And CheckBox14.Value = False And CheckBox15.Value = False Then


Sheets("Sheet3").Range("B4").Select
ActiveCell.EntireRow.Insert shift:=xlDown

Sheets("sheet3").Range("B4:E4").Select
Selection.Borders.Weight = xlThin

Sheets("sheet3").Range("B4").Select
ActiveCell.Value = "=b5+1"

Sheets("sheet3").Range("A4").Select
Selection.Borders.Weight = xlThin
ActiveCell.Value = "OE"
End If

If CheckBox1.Value = True And CheckBox4.Value = True And CheckBox7.Value = False And CheckBox2.Value = False And CheckBox3.Value = False And CheckBox6.Value = True And CheckBox5.Value = False And CheckBox8.Value = False And CheckBox9.Value = False _
And CheckBox10.Value = False And CheckBox11.Value = False And CheckBox12.Value = False And CheckBox13.Value = True And CheckBox14.Value = False And CheckBox15.Value = False Then


Sheets("Sheet3").Range("B4").Select
ActiveCell.EntireRow.Insert shift:=xlDown

Sheets("sheet3").Range("B4:E4").Select
Selection.Borders.Weight = xlThin

Sheets("sheet3").Range("B4").Select
ActiveCell.Value = "=b5+1"

Sheets("sheet3").Range("A4").Select
Selection.Borders.Weight = xlThin
ActiveCell.Value = "OF"
End If

If CheckBox1.Value = True And CheckBox4.Value = True And CheckBox7.Value = False And CheckBox2.Value = False And CheckBox3.Value = False And CheckBox6.Value = True And CheckBox5.Value = False And CheckBox8.Value = False And CheckBox9.Value = False _
And CheckBox10.Value = False And CheckBox11.Value = False And CheckBox12.Value = False And CheckBox13.Value = False And CheckBox14.Value = True And CheckBox15.Value = False Then


Sheets("Sheet3").Range("B4").Select
ActiveCell.EntireRow.Insert shift:=xlDown

Sheets("sheet3").Range("B4:E4").Select
Selection.Borders.Weight = xlThin

Sheets("sheet3").Range("B4").Select
ActiveCell.Value = "=b5+1"

Sheets("sheet3").Range("A4").Select
Selection.Borders.Weight = xlThin
ActiveCell.Value = "OG"
End If

If CheckBox1.Value = True And CheckBox4.Value = True And CheckBox7.Value = False And CheckBox2.Value = False And CheckBox3.Value = False And CheckBox6.Value = True And CheckBox5.Value = False And CheckBox8.Value = False And CheckBox9.Value = False _
And CheckBox10.Value = False And CheckBox11.Value = False And CheckBox12.Value = False And CheckBox13.Value = False And CheckBox14.Value = False And CheckBox15.Value = True Then


Sheets("Sheet3").Range("B4").Select
ActiveCell.EntireRow.Insert shift:=xlDown

Sheets("sheet3").Range("B4:E4").Select
Selection.Borders.Weight = xlThin

Sheets("sheet3").Range("B4").Select
ActiveCell.Value = "=b5+1"

Sheets("sheet3").Range("A4").Select
Selection.Borders.Weight = xlThin
ActiveCell.Value = "OH"
End If



End Sub

Private Sub CheckBox2_Click()
Dim answer As VbMsgBoxResult
Dim addname As String



If CheckBox2.Value = True Then
answer = MsgBox("Voulez-vous saisir le RNC?", vbYesNo)
If answer = vbYes Then
addname = InputBox("Inscrivez le RNC")
Sheets("Sheet4").Range("B4").Select
ActiveCell.EntireRow.Insert shift:=xlDown

Sheets("sheet4").Range("B4:E4").Select
Selection.Borders.Weight = xlThin

Sheets("sheet4").Range("A4").Select
Selection.Borders.Weight = xlThin
ActiveCell.Value = addname

Else
Exit Sub
End If
End If

Unload Me

End Sub
```

Comment: Where do you have the code the initializes/activates the user form?  Is it in a module or in a sheet object?  Can you post that portion?

Comment: it's in ''FORMS'' inside ''UserForm1''. It's a GUI. @Jenn

Comment: You're welcome!  I added a few extra suggestions for you in the answer as UPDATE #1.  Let me know if that helps.

Comment: I see that Sheet4 is sometimes spelled with a capital S and sometimes with a lowercase s.  It is case sensitive, so change which ever one is not correct.  Same thing for Sheet2 and Sheet3 also.

Comment: ... It worked.. I only had to activate the sheets.. so i worte Sheet2.activate ...sheet3.activate and so on ... lol...

Comment: OK. I made it work. I just had to add Sheet(2,3,4).Activate after every "if".

Comment: Great!  I'm glad it worked out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I only had to add the `Activate` method. If I'm in sheet1 and I wanted to do something that is inside sheet2 I need to write:

```
If statement
Sheet2.Activate
*insert rest of code you want*
end if
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of how you can conditionally call user forms.

Example: Two different user forms exist. The user forms are triggered by hyperlink clicks. They hyperlinks both exist on the same worksheet, each activates a different user form, but both are controlled by the same Worksheet_FollowHyperlink change event.

This is the code snippet in the Worksheet_FollowHyperlink change event that activates the respective user form based on which hyperlink is clicked.

```
On Error Resume Next

Select Case Target.Parent

    Case Range("macro_Help_CSVFiles")

        UF_Help_CSVFiles.Show

    Case Range("macro_Help_TBG")

        UF_Help_TBG.Show

End Select
```

Inside the user form code, there are several subs (button clicks, actions that occur upon activation, etc).  Because the user form can be called multiple times and needs to work each time, it needs to be unloaded according to the intended sequence of events.

Here is where I have hidden the user form and displayed the next based on a button click.

```
Private Sub CommandButton_ContactUs_Click()

    'Hide this user form
    Me.Hide

    'And display the next user form.
    UF_Help_EmailUs.Show

End Sub
```

And here is where the sequence of events is complete, so just before the end, the user form is unloaded so it can be ready to be called again from a fresh start.

```
ReleaseVariables:

    Set objOutlook = Nothing
    Set objMail = Nothing
    strTo = vbNullString
    strSubject = vbNullString
    strBody = vbNullString
    strCarrier = vbNullString
    strCoverageMonth = vbNullString

    GoTo ResetAppSettings

ResetAppSettings:

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

Unload Me


End Sub
```

Without seeing the portions of the code that call/hide/unload the user form, it's hard to say where the issue is occurring, but these should give you some good ideas of where and how to route the code.

If it's needing to be called from two different worksheets based on a change event in each particular sheet, you may want to place your code in a module and then call the sub from a change event in both worksheets, making sure to add conditions for running each part and unloading.

UPDATE #1

If all of the code currently resides in the user form and you just need an action to call the user form, then try this...

On the first worksheet, add a command button.  (Developer > Controls > Insert > ActiveX > Command Button).  Then right-click on the command button and choose View Code.  This will create a command button click event on that worksheet.  Add the code to activate your user form there, like this:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

'UF_Help_CSVFiles is the name of my user form.
UF_Help_CSVFiles.Show

End Sub
```

Then go to the second worksheet and do the same thing.  Add a command button and add the same code.

If the ToggleButton1 click event and the Checkbox2 click event are completely separate procedures and contain no shared references, then right before the ToggleButton End Sub and right before the Checkbox2 End Sub, unload your user form by adding a line for `Unload Me`.

Walk through your new procedure in the VB editor by starting with the the command button code on the first worksheet and pressing F8 to test each line through to the end. If all goes well you should be able to move on to the next command button code on the 2nd worksheet, doing the same thing.

Comment: Thank you @jenn, but I didn't understand much since i'm pretty new to vba. All i know is that my entire code is in  ''userform1''. I will try to play with it a bit and see what happens... I wish I knew where to place the code.

Comment: it's not working.. i've copied the code on your UPDATE#1 in the command button of sheet 1 and 2. I also added ```Unload me``` just before End Sub ... still got the error..

Comment: Did you add the command button objects to sheets 1 and 2?  Did you also change the user form name in the command button code?  The user form name in the code I pasted was for one of my user forms.  You will need to change the name to match your user form.  What is the error you are receiving?  On which line of the code does it occur when you F8 to step through?

Comment: yes. Still not working... "Select method of range class failed"

Comment: With that error, there is a problem somewhere else in the code.  Can you post the code for the entire user form?

Comment: just did, edited the code in the post. Thank you so much.